# How to set number of processes in mpi4py

Tags: python, mpi

How do I set a fixed number of processes in mpi4py? In other languages` mpi implementations it is passed in init(args) as argument. The documentation does not seem to mention this. Does anyone know how to do this? The program will be launched on regular dual core laptop and 24 nodes (96 cores) cluster and I would like to emulate the cluster on the laptop.

PS. Sorry if it actually is in the documentation - it is quite cryptic to someone new to mpi.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easiest is just to use mpiexec (or mpirun) to launch the program, specifying the number of MPI tasks you want:

```
$ cat foo.py
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
nprocs = comm.Get_size()
rank   = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
   data = 'Hello!'
   comm.send(data, dest=nprocs-1, tag=1)
elif rank == nprocs-1:
   data = comm.recv(source=0, tag=1)
   print 'Rank ', rank, ' received ', data

$ mpiexec -np 4 python foo.py
Rank  3  received  Hello!
```

Note, though, that running with 96 tasks on your laptop is probably not going to be especially useful.

Comment: It is not about usefullness, it is for testing purposes. Anyway, I did launch the program through the command line especially since Eclipse seems to have a problem passing arguments in PyDev.

Comment: Yeah, but even the testing isn't likely to be useful.   If there are parallel errors you're testing for, a lot of them will be hidden by the fact that you're only running on ~4 cores.   But on the other hand, if you just need to make sure your problem is decomposed correctly with 96 tasks, it'll work fine.

Comment: I've noticed that mpiexec seems to work better than mpirun when using Python+MPI.

Answer (score 2):

The [mpi4py tutorial](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html) does it like this:

```
from mpi4py import MPI    
import sys
client_script = 'my_client.py'
comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable, args=[client_script], maxprocs=5)
```

Comment: I've never noticed the Spawn method, it's really helpful in some cases.